# Entity Data Model Wizard crashes on Specify connection string dialog

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to add an entity data model in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 I see the following.

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?  I see the dialog to specify a database connection appear for a split second then dissapears.

Comment: Attach a new instance of VS to this instance and see what exception is that - depending on the exception stack trace might be crucial here. Also, does this happen only with the "EF Designer from Database" option or all options?

Comment: Possibly one of your server Explorer data connections are corrupt - http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2010/08/fixing-the-server-explorer-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-error.html

Answer (score 28):

I found a solution.  Go into view->Server Explorer and remove any "Data Connections". Then this worked again.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had the same issue and this worked for me. I am starting to hate entity framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really saved some time.

Comment: great.. i had the same issue and worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 22):

I solved it by doing the following.

- Make sure the versions of MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entities, MySql.Web dll files in C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net x.x.x\Assemblies\v4.5 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies are the same.
- Make sure your project references the same version of dll

In my case my

- MySql connector was 6.9.6
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net x.x.x\Assemblies\v4.5 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies had it as 6.8.3
- Project referenced 6.8.3.

After updating all versions with same dlls, now I am able to update the "Model from database"

Hope this helps someone

Edit: A few weeks after there was some windows update which again screwed up the settings. To resolve it, I had to re-run the My Sql Connector installation and My Sql for Visual Studio, it worked fine after that.

Comment: I love you, man. Oh, and it didn't work right after deleting and re-adding the MySQL references. Restarting VS did.

Comment: Muthu - Good idea, I wouldn't have found that one... What version did you choose? I had 6.9.7, 6.9.6, and 6.7.4... Should I take the latest version from NuGet, the one on `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL`, or the one on `Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies `? I tried the latest version but it still crashes. Sad story.

Comment: I took the latest version from MySql installation folder and matched them

Comment: I updated Mysql.Data, but found I needed to uninstall mysql.data.entities and install mysql.data.entity

Comment: The re-install of Visual Studio for Mysql did it for me, Dlls were already aligned. EF can be a pain to re-setup, but it is smooth otherwise.

Comment: Just as Muthu points out, the installed version of MySQL connector on the system must match the MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity and MySql.Web versions in your project.

Comment: Thanks - I had a miner older version of the connector installed (6.9.8) and used the newest nuget packages (6.9.9)

Answer (score 0):

Delete all connections in the Database Explorer Window and in the ADO .Net wizard add a new connection. I was able to solve this problem this way.

Answer (score 0):

you have to delete all other connection from server explorer and delete other connection ss web.config

Answer (score 0):

I Had a similar problem, spent 2 days trying many solutions but I finally solved. I just had to :
- Install MySQL For Visual Studio 2.0.5 
- uninstall and install MySQL Connector 6.9.9
Note: Please follow the order VS => Connector and respect the version.

Finally I faced other problem and solved by adding an empty **emdx** first then changing `SSL Generate Template` property from **SSDLToSQL** To **SSDLTOMySQL**

Answer (score 0):

Install MySql for VS 1.2.9

Install MySql Connector 6.8.3

Add these Nuget Packages to your Project:

```
EntityFramework    //  6.4
Mysql.Data      //  6.8.8
Mysql.Data.Entities   // 6.8.3  
Mysql.Web  //   6.8.8
```

In the Solution Explorer, edit App.config(Add or Replace):

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
         <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

rebuild and nothing more

Answer (score 0):

For Anyone having this issue in VS 2019. This is what I did after a week long troubleshooting and googling, I just remove:
EntityFramework
MySql.Data.Framework or MySql.Data (or any other MySQL Nugget Packages you have added)
Then I re-install just this two in same order:
EntityFramework
MySQL.Data.EntityFramework

Then Update you entityframework section in app.config/web.config as follows:

I did not add default connection factory, I also remove version info from MySQL