# Entity Framework wizard crashes on MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875915/entity-data-model-wizard-crashes-on-specify-connection-string-dialog) but the crash happens later. I **must** interoperate an EF database-first model between SQL Server and MySQL. More specifically, my application had plain SQL queries fired to either SQL Server or MySQL according to connection string and configuration setting (`DB_TYPE=MYSQL`, etc.), having both databases with same structure and maintained together, so that each modification to one's schema was reapplied to the other.

Now I added EF support to the application using SQL Server database-first model. I **must** now let the application run on MySQL too. In order to verify that the old developer didn't leave something disaligned between the two DBMSes, I tried to `Update model against database`* and this time I selected the MySQL connection to my development database on localhost.

After I click `Next` on the screen below, it will simply crash and return to EDMX editor

[image: Data Model wizard]

I need to go ahead with the project, I'm stuck on this since a while.

Here is my Web.config fragment:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

How can I solve my problem? I reinstalled MySQL tools for Visual Studio but didn't help.

*I use a localized version of Visual Studio, so I don't know the original English for all commands

Comment: I face a similar issue. Did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: I know that this is not an answer but Database First is not a good approach to access different DBMS types. In EF7 is not supported anymore, EF providers are very hard to write and often there are issues like your. The best approach is to generate classes from database with a tool like CodeSmith or something similar then go on with a Code First approach.

Comment: Any errors in any log?

Comment: Is this related? [Entity Data Model Wizard crashes on Specify connection string dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25875915/7586)

Comment: Yes, related. But at least I can complete one more step

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't see you already linked to it. So you didn't find a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework + MySQL class generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874607/entity-framework-mysql-class-generating)

Comment: @ bubi  Sorry but I totally disagree. Code first is a terrible solution for large projects and relational dbs and can generate horrible table sets that need hundreds of joins in queries. Database First allows the database to be treated as a first class citizen with all the care and attention it needs to perform well. I have worked on many code first projects and all have had major issues.

Comment: This link provided a solution for me:  https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,667307,667319#msg-667319

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why this works but I went in to my NuGet Package Manager and removed the MySql.Data.Entity (also checked dependencies which removed MySql.Data). I went into my .edmx and ran the 'Update model from database...' and everything worked.

(Note: This also removed my entity framework so I had to add that back in using the NuGet Manager)

W...T...F?

Maybe others can confirm this...

Comment: Could you reproduce (e.g. checkout an earlier version from source code...?) and confirm which packages to remove? So we can reproduce on our side and confirm. Actually yours looks more like a comment of a confused user. I would suggest taking a short breath and investigate. By the way MySQL packages have been upgraded since question day zero

Comment: Yeah I've actually been able to reproduce this on a daily basis. The MySql connection stops working randomly, and in order to fix this I have to uninstall and reinstall the packages using NuGet. If you know of any error logs I can check I'd love to find out what is causing this.

Answer (score 3):

It has been answered in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110060/entity-frameworks-entity-data-wizard-crashes-when-connecting-to-mysql-database), the typical crash reason is the mismatched versions of MySQL connector and MySQL.Data.Entity.

And most likely reason for you to get the wrong version is because of the package name changed from MySQL.Data.Entity to **MySql.Data.EntityFramework**.

I was spending a lot of time on trying the answers in the thread, so just FYI.

Comment: Thank you. I installed a newer version of MySql.Data package and replaced MySql.Data.Entity with MySql.Data.EntityFramework (of the same version as MySql.Data) and it helped.

Answer (score 2):

When you look around this seems to be a common problem.  I know this way along the trail but late is better then never.

I eventually removed and reinstalled visual studio 2015 and mysql and then started from scratch.    I then ensured that I walked through the process bringing in only what was needed.

1. Using nuget install MySql.Data  6.9.9  and MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.9. Nothing else.
2. Nuget does not change the web config correctly so you need to change it as below.

Before

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
         <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
     </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

After

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

This fixed it for me.     I am not sure that you need do the reinstall, but for sure you need do step 2.

Good luck.

Comment: Worth to give a try

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by following the steps below (note that im using vs2015 and .net 4.5)

1) Uninstall all previous mysql connectors that you have

2) Remove all mySQL references through NuGet packages

3) Download mysql connector v6.8.8

4) Once this is downloaded, go to your project and add as reference the newly installed dll files (located in the installation path, typically C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.8.8\Assemblies\v4.5)

5) Go to your NuGet packages and add MySql.Data (Version 6.8) and MySql.Data.Entity (Version 6.8).

6) Build your solution and no more crash :)

Hope this helps you out

Comment: This was the only solution I could find spending hours for this particular problem. Amazing! Thank you so much! You are a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who's still encountering this issue here are the versions that I had to install to get it working:

MySQL for Visual Studio: 2.0.5 (note that at the time of posting the latest General Availability release is 1.2.9 - you'll need to go to the Development Releases tab to get version 2.0.5 - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)

MySQL Connector/NET: 6.9.11 (https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/)

MySQL.Data NuGet package: 6.9.11 (Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.9.11)

MySQL.Data.Entity NuGet package: 6.9.11 (Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version 6.9.11)

(Note that I didn't have to adjust the config file.)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Some of these versions no longer show up in the NuGet Package Manager interface but still work if you put the entry into the command-line console.

As well as 
Install-Package MySql.Web -Version 6.9.11

If you need that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the compatibility of MySQL, Visual Studio, connector and MySQL for Visual Studio.

---

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. You need to uninstall MySQL Connector and MySQL for Visual Studio. (Restart your computer)
3. If you have two versions of the visual studio it will work only in one of them. So choose which you want.
4. Install the correct versions. (Restart your computer).

   - Visual Studio 2019 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise)
     `-` MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9 with Connector/NET 8.0.14
   - Visual Studio 2017 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise):
     `-`MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7  with Connector/NET 6.9.9
   - Visual Studio 2015 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise):
     `-`MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7 or 2.0.2 with Connector/NET 6.9.8
5. Open VS and build your project then try to update your entities

[image]
Actually I'm using VS professional 2017 with this nuggets MySql.Data 6.9.9 and MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.9(MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7  with Connector/NET 6.9.9)

Comment: MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9 with Connector/NET 8.0.14 didn't fix my problem

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the trouble was a **specific version of MySQL Server**. So I have uninstalled everything and made a clean install with these versions.

This is the setup that worked with **VisualStudio 2019 Community**:

1. Close VisualStudio
2. Uninstall (from Windows Control Panel):

   - **MySQL for VisualStudio**
   - **MySQL Connector Net**
   - **MySQL Server**
3. Check **PrivateAssemblies** folder and delete any **MySQL.*** assemblies:

   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
4. If needed, install **MySQL Server version 5.7.33**.

   - Workbench can be any version.
   - Setup your server.
5. Install **MySQL Connector Net 6.8.8**

   - This version is not available at MySQL archives. You can find mirrors looking for the name: **mysql-connector-net-6.8.8.msi**
6. Install **MySQL for VisualStudio 1.2.8**

At this point, **you can open** VS and test generation of EntityFramework model

To build and run:

7. Reference needed assemblies from the folder:

   - C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.8.8\Assemblies\v4.5
8. Make sure your project target framework version is compatible with MySQL assemblies (**v4.5**)
9. Look for MySQL references on your config files to point version 6.8.8

References:

- [Nassif Bousaba answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091852/1293235)
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89338

Answer (score 1):

Well I can tell you that connector 8.0.xxx and all of the 8.0.xxx dll's that MySQL has put out for MySql Server 8 are a complete bust.

There has been a major bug out https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91030&thanks=3&notify=195  for over a year now.

If your trying to work with MySql 8.0 many of the connectors and libraries will give you an error....

"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."

It is a testament to the absolutely sub zero level of visual studio support, documentation, testing and basic development skill applied in the mysql  dll's connector and documentation that I have spent the last 40 hrs of my waking life trying to put together a working model to get my application to connect with MySql 8.0.16  and to have a working entity framework wizard.   At this point I am almost wishing I developed it using SQL Server.

I am using a variant of  ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and this is what I would get back when trying to log in

"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."

Anyway here is what I got to work for me.

This is something I got to work with Server 8.0 on Windows 10 that does a connection and allows log in with ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and will at least run the Data Entity Wizard to completion.

Install Connector / Net 6.10.7

DLL's

c:..\EntityFramework.6.2.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll

C:..\EntityFramework.6.2.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

C:..\MySql.Data.6.10.7\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll

C:..\MySql.Data.6.10.7\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll

```
Web.Config

<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,publicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />      
    </configSections>

<connectionStrings>
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=<yourid>;password=<yourpassword>;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=<yourdbname>" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>


<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>

     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
 <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
        </providers>
</entityFramework>

<system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
       <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.10.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

I hope this helps some people out there but I have a funny feeling your mileage may vary.

Comment: I'm starting to understand the guy who applied to a software job and got hired, fixed a bug that had been frustrating him as a user, then quit.

Comment: @LiterateCorvette   True that.  I have just got back into it and found this link.   https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tutorial-use-entity-framework-core-5-0-in-net-core-3-1-with-mysql-database-by2/

Works like cool breeze on a hot summer day

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  After installing 'MySql.Data 6.9.9' and 'MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.9' Nuget packages, the wizard crashed after that screen.  I attached a debugger to it and found it was caused by a null reference exception in MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll.

I figured it may not be the packages, since I already tried reinstalling them, so I figured it might be an issue with the MySQL install for Visual Studio conflicting with the MySQL EF6 dll. The solution for me was simply to reinstall the latest "MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6":

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Could be I had an older version (didn't think to check first, so I can't confirm).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause was that the version of the installed mysql connector was different from the version of referenced MySQL.Data.Entity
When I referenced the same version all became alright.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the link will remain around but this works very well for .net core.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tutorial-use-entity-framework-core-5-0-in-net-core-3-1-with-mysql-database-by2/

In summary the trick seems to be to use

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (v5.0.0 – the latest stable version)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (v5.0.0 – the latest stable version)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (version 5.0.0-alpha.2)
```

in your in your package manager. Made it pretty smooth.

I have been seriously unimpressed by other releases that are not Pomelo.

Using MySQL Connector Net 6.10.7 and Server 8.0

Comment: BrownPony, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Shree I added what I believe is the essence of the article.  It is too long to post. If you think it should be deleted then I am okay with that.

Answer (score -1):

I change config file from

```
<entityFramework>.....</entityFramework>
```

to

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">.....</entityFramework>
```

and everything works

reference:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html