# Entity Framework's Entity Data Wizard Crashes When Connecting to MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I am attempting to create an Entity Data Model using the wizard to reverse engineer an existing MySQL database. I get to the Choose Your Data Connection page of the wizard, select an existing MySQL connection and click Next, and the wizard crashes. Specifically, the dialog box just disappears without an error message or any trace. Every single time. Restarting VS or Windows does nothing.

I can connect to the database using Server Explorer and the same connection without problem, so I'm fairly confident it isn't a connection problem.

This is in Visual Studio 2015 with all updates installed, version 1.2.6 of MySQL for Visual Studio, EF 6.1.3, and MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 versions 6.8.3.0. It is a Console application targeting the .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Google hasn't revealed anything useful yet. Another [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082126/ado-net-entity-data-model-wizard-crashes-if-adding-mysql-assemblies-to-project) from yesterday is similar, but is crashing at a different point and that user can't connect using Server Explorer. So it seems to be a different situation.

There is nothing in the Windows logs that is of any help.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I've just tried this on another Windows 10 machine, similarly configured. And the same thing happens: the wizard just shuts down when it attempts to make a connection to the database.

Comment: I know this is VS2015 and Connector/NET 6.8.3.0, but wanted to share my experience with the latest and greatest, VS2017 Community and Connector/NET 8.0.11.0. Basically it was a miserable failure with the ADO.net data model wizard crashing at various places with no error message. Uninstalling and reverting to Connector/NET 6.10.7 (last one before the jump to 8) fixed it right up.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is caused by version mismatch.

On my system, I had MySQL Connector 6.9.6.
Issuing the command in NuGet Package Manger Console:

Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity
installs version 6.9.8 by default. Your connector must match the actual version of the NuGet Package.
You can download an updated version of the connector from: https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Here select the "Ado.net driver for MySQL", and download the corresponding version (in this case 6.9.8). Reopen Visual Studio and now the wizard does not crash. No reboot required.

Comment: Thanks! But my project has MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity versions 6.9.9 installed. And I already had version 6.9.9 of Connector/Net. I downloaded a fresh copy and did a repair, to no effect.

BUT I decided to uninstall Connector/Net and reinstall it. That did the trick...kind of. I'm now getting to the NEXT page of the wizard, where I choose my version of EF--progress! Which has an error message about not having a compatible version of EF even though I'm using the latest version. So at least it's a new problem, so I'll move on to that one.

Comment: This worked for me. Had `Connector 6.8.8` but version `6.9.9` of `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity`. Rolling the NuGet packages back to `6.8.8` got everything working. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here - dialog would simply close with no obvious error message.  Ensuring installed `Connector.Net` version was the same as the one referenced in App.Config (and Nuget) fixed the issue. Can I suggest this could this be marked as the correct answer?

Comment: hThis answer should be marked as the right answer! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Really helped me!

Comment: Same issue here. I am using Connector/NET v6.10.4 , MySql.Data v6.10.4 , MySql.Data.Entity v6.10.4 and MySql.Data.Entities v6.8.3. Still the dialog simply closes

Comment: Have a look at my solution down here if you still have this problem :)
short: use MySql.Data.EntityFramework, NOT Mysql.Data.Entity

Comment: A minor bit of clarification: this is a mismatch between the installed MySQL DLLs(MySql.data and MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 in my case), of which multiple versions can be installed simultaneously, and MySQL Connector.Net. The MySQL Installer will replace the old version of Connector.Net when it updates. This only becomes a problem when I need to regenerate the ADO.Net data model from a DB, which crashes if Connector.Net version doesn't match the DLL versions.

Comment: Not working in 2019 VS.. same versions still wizard crash after selecting database connections and no error is shown

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem today, following the tips here that it is a "version mismatch" is completely correct!

My important "discovery" is that they have renamed the package you need for EF6!
As many people here has discovered (for example "Nofi"), downgrading to match versions fixes the problem. However, **instead of downgrading the new versions, swap out the Mysql.Data.Entity package for the newer MySql.Data.EntityFramework**! :)

short: use **MySql.Data.EntityFramework**, NOT **Mysql.Data.Entity**

Comment: This is the correct answer - The documentation provided by oracle is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Out of sheer luck and chance, I happened upon the same error.
I am using VS 2015 with Entity Framework 6 as well. The error also happened as I was attempting to create the model from the database using EF reverse engineering existing connection.

The problem is that even though the data connection exists, and you can refresh it, somehow the connection is broken. Go to the **Server Explorer** panel on the left, then under **Data Connections** find your existing connection, and instead of checking it using **refresh**, right click it and choose **Modify Connection**.

From here try testing the connection and pressing OK. You should get an error (for me it said '**Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.**')

Comment: Thanks! But, alas, that didn't work. The test connection from the Modify Connection dialog box connected successfully, but the wizard still dies at the same place.

Comment: @RiverRunner same here, just closes the window, no error.

Comment: Since the year I answered this question, I would like to think I have a better solution. Back to basics: Reinstall 'mysql for VS' (while making sure your version is correct) and make sure the dll is referenced (I think there are 2-3) also the app.config has to be correctly set up. If you're having problems, @IdanShechter create a new question, I will try to answer that if I can.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue it was because I was using **Mysql connector v 8.0.12** ,**MySql.Data v8.0.12** and **Mysql.Data.Entity v6.10.8**.

The program crashes because of compatibility issues.What worked for me is I installed all three of the same version

**Mysql connector v 6.10.8** and **MySql.Data v6.10.8** and **Mysql.Data.Entity v6.10.8**.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, worked for me on VS2015.

Answer (score 2):

This keeps happening with VS2017 and the latest MySQL connector (6.10.6). Downgrading both the connector and the Nuget package to 6.9.11 works.

Comment: Question specifically mentions Visual Studio 2015

Comment: This is also happening to me with latest 6.10.6 and Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Confirmed it works downgrading to 6.9.11. I also had to downgrade entity framework from 6.2 to 6.1.3 for 6.9.11 to be compatible with EF.

Comment: Still happening with version 8.0.11, will raise a problem report with MySql and post a link here...

Comment: New bug report here. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91201&thanks=4 It's really unconscionable that there's no log or even detailed descriptive and instructive error message. :(

Answer (score 2):

For those struggling in Visual Studio 2019 Community, I applied the solution provided at [dev.mysql.com.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html)
The following configuration works for me:

MySQL Installer:

- **MySQL Server 8.0.14**
- MySQL Workbench 8.0.14 [probably optional]
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9
- MySQL Shell 8.0.14 [probably optional]
- Connector/NET 6.10.8

NuGet packages:

- EntityFramework v6.4.4
- **MySql.Data v8.0.14**
- **MySql.Data.EntityFramework v8.0.14**

Note: Items in **bold** must have exactly the same version.

After running the installations, Visual Studio prompted for an update to one of the connectors. Once the update was applied (only a couple of minutes for that bit), the system is working.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented to Lars Meldgård, uninstalling and reinstalling version 6.9.9 of Connector/Net got me one page further in the wizard. So I'll take that as a win. But I'm really confused why this worked. I was getting the problem on two different computers, my main desktop machine and my laptop. Similar configurations in Windows 10 with everything up to date, so were both corrupted? Not likely.

So now the problem is on the Choose Your Version page of the wizard, where I'm getting the error below. But that is a different problem, which I'll tackle next.

[New error on next page of wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1llWB.jpg)

Comment: Make sure you have rebuilt your application after updating EF versions. Even if you do not have any code yet, you need to rebuild for the wizard to work.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to programming/.Net development. I had the same problem where the window disappears when I try and generate a entity model from MySql database.

I tried the matching versions of Nuget packages and connector but still no joy. What I did to get it working is as follows:

- I removed and then re-created the project(lucky it was a new project)
  -Then generated the model from the Database
- Then I installed the Nuget packages to match the version of my connector.

I am using VS 2017 Community Edition,
Connector V6.9.9,
Nuget packages V6.8.8

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Since the highest version of MySql.Data.Enetity is v6.10.8 I can find via nuget, I have downloaded the "mysql-connector-net-6.10.8.msi " so then I downgraded MySql.Data to v.6.10.8, that did trick!

Answer (score 1):

The mismatches seem to be on the exact version of the MySQL Connector Net.  I have many projects in dev and prod with "MySQL Connector Net 8.0.13" and am not able to upgrade across the board yet.  The current NuGet package was "MySQL Connector Net **8.0.15**".  I had to uninstall both "MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.15" and "MySql.Data 8.0.15" and then force the version with command line installs to match the current version of MySQL Connector Net that I run in dev and prod:

```
PM> Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 8.0.13
PM> Install-Package MySql.Data.EntityFramework -Version 8.0.13
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed this by renaming the folder c:\users\myusername\appdata\roaming\microsoft\visualstudio\10.0 to "10.0 old"

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my issue I finally resolved, as this is a real headache to catch.

I had a Role ID column in Table Role initially set to number(38,0) in SQL and created it that way, and then changed to NUMBER(10,0) and changed it.
After days of trying to resolve this, I finally right clicked the tables in the Server connection, and clicking Designer.  My one table : Role, had a column ID - type number(10,0). It was linked to Table USER as RoleID. After checking the RoleID in table USER, in the designer it was showing up as Number(38,0) .
So check your foreign keys one by one...  This was my issue which cost me 3 days to finally catch.  My EF Dialog box also just disappeared, or would give me no tables in the EDMX file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
```

I changed the version of MySql.Data.EntityFramework to 8.0.16 because my connector 8.0.16 and problem has vanished. this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Installing MySQL 8.0 Server with EntityFramework in Visual Studio 2019
Install MySQL Server 8.0.16

Install Complete MySQL Connector.Net x86 8.0.16

Install this custom repacked VSIX MySQL Visual Studio

If after installing MySQL Visual Studio Plugin it shows warning that failed to execute comamnd devenv /updateconfiguration, then manually execute that command in Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 20xx with run as administrator.

Run this command Install-Package EntityFramework in Visual Studio Nuget package manager console

Manage Nuget Packages > Search Mysql > install Mysql.Data v8.0.16

Manage Nuget Packages > Search Mysql > install Mysql.Data.Entity v6.10.8

Manage Nuget Packages > Search Mysql.Data.EntityFramework > install Mysql.Data.EntityFramework v8.0.16

Add this lines if its not automatically added after  tag in Web.config and rebuild solution
  
    
    
      
      
      </provider>-->
      
      
    
  
Even if doing all the above process some error occurs, then try uninstall nuget packages all the above added and UnInstall-Package EntityFramework uninstall visual studio plugin and connector net. Then rebuild fresh project, and add only Install-Package EntityFramework and then add references only Mysql.Data and Mysql.Data.EntityFramework for EF6 and then add the provider xml in web.config as mentioned above and remove the white space between the  and  tags, and rebuild project and finally try to add model.

This process is tested and working for .Net Framework 4.7.2 on Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2019, I had `MySql.Data-8.2.0` but I had different version of `MySql.Data.EntityFramework-8.0.11`

I updated `MySql.Data.EntityFramework` to `8.2.0` which resolved the issue for me. Entity Wizard came up fine after updating this package.