# Visual Studio Entity framework wizard crash on MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

During any action with Entity framework wizard on MySQL connection - it crushes on second page without any errors.

Problem is the same as in [Entity Framework wizard crashes on MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140079/entity-framework-wizard-crashes-on-mysql)

We have tried all advices from where and no one helped. 
We have tried Visual studio 2015\2017 several versions (community, pro, ent), different versions of MySQL connector (6.8.x, 6.9.x and 6.10.x) and mysql for visual studio different versions 1.2.x 
MySQL server was used also with several versions: 5.7.20, 21 and so on.
No success at all
Logging for Visual studio is also not helpful, nothing about this crash there.
One last not checked point - is debugging EF6 for MySQL, but it is not clear how it helps. 
Any clues or options how to resolve it?

Comment: Please clarify what crushes on second page.  Change it to either MySQL or Entity framework, or whatever is crushing  If it is MySQL, ensure SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "log_error"; has a file name to record errors.  Post your MySQL error log into your question, please.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in MySQL Connector/NET: [bug 89338](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89338). According to that bug report, there's a bug in the wizard code that does not appear to have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the direct answer but I had much headache and a lack of documentation while I was trying to connect EF to MySql on .NET Core project. Now I'm using SQLite and SQL Server localdb with no problems at all. If your task has no constraints for you DB provider I'd recommend you to do as I've done.