# Entity Framework + MySQL class generating

Tags: c#, mysql

I try to connect MySql database by using Entity Framework but visual studio do not want to generate *.edmx?

I have 1 table in db,
-choose ado.net edm,
-select the Generate from Database
-choose db
-here I think I should select tables, but the **wizard closes**

I try to use different version of EF, but still nothing works. What is the problem?

my software:
-Windows 7 *64
-vs 2017 community
-mySql 8.0 community

Comment: What connector are you using?  You need the MySQL specific connector.  It's in Nuget.  Documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entity-framework.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in MySQL Connector/NET:

- [Bug 89338](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89338) for 6.10.5
- [Bug 91195](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91195) for 8.10.11

You will need to wait for Oracle to fix this bug and ship an update. Some people have reported being able to work around the problem by following [these instructions](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,667307,667319#msg-667319).

See also these previous SO questions:

- [Visual Studio Entity framework wizard crash on MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206081/visual-studio-entity-framework-wizard-crash-on-mysql/49215311)
- [Entity Framework wizard crashes on MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140079/entity-framework-wizard-crashes-on-mysql)

Comment: Ok, thabks! I'll wait.

Comment: they say in Bug 89338 it would be fixed in 6.10.7.0... doesn't look like to me...